# configuring a bean as 'optional' in spring applicationcontext.xml

Tags: spring, selenium, applicationcontext, option-type

I have following bean defined in my spring `appicationcontext.xml`

```
<bean id ="seleniumDriver" class="org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="capabilities"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I provide the reference for this bean runtime with the below command

```
mvn clean test -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="C:\Program Files\Mozilla\Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

I have a requirement where I don't want to load that bean so I run my project ommitting the webdriver parameter i.e. 'mvn clean test' but then I get the below exception.

Caused by:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'seleniumDriver' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed.`
```

I was reading some posts here and got to know that we can use `@Autowired(required=false)` or overriding `applicationcontext` in java class but I don't want to touch java code and want to do it through XML configuration, is there any way?

Comment: Use bean profiles and when needed activate the beans in that profile.